# PHP how can I find out right properties within Object

Tags: php, object, conditional-statements

```
class a {
    public $a = "3";
    public $b = "0";
    public $b = "3";
    public $c = "0";
    public $d = "0";
    public $e = "0";
    public $g = "0";
}
```

How can I find out which properties are greater than zero?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`get_class_vars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-vars.php) function outside the object itself like that:

```
$a = new a();

$class_vars = get_class_vars(get_class($a));

foreach ($class_vars as $name => $value) {
    if ($value > 0) {
         echo "$name : $value\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put this method inside your class and it will return all vars in array:

```
public function test() {
    $vars = get_object_vars($this);
    $r = array();
    foreach($vars as $k => $v) {
        if($v > 0){ $r[$k] = $v; }
    }
    return $r;
}
```